# How to select range for two operations?

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to calculate average and standard deviation for 60000 data set (so the NR=60000). My data set file has two columns and my concern is in column #2. I want to use "awk" to do the job. The script goes as below:

```
awk '   { sum+=$2; array[NR]=$2 }
        END {for(x=10000;x<=NR;x++) {sumsq+=((array[x]-(sum/NR))^2);} 
        printf("%8.3f\t%8.3f\n"), (sum/NR), sqrt(sumsq/NR)  }' < $fileIn
```

I want the code to choose only the range from 10000 to 60000 to calculate the average and the standard deviation.

For standard deviation the code chooses range 10000 to 60000 but for average it uses range from 1-60000.

How can I choose the range 10000-60000 for both the  calculations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output and make it something we can test against. Just use 10 lines total starting at line 4 for the calculation instead of 6000 lines starting at line 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to limit which lines to do calculations, using the `NR` variable. And for results, I'm not into maths, but you should not choose the whole length of the file (`NR`), but the length of the lines used for calculations (`length(array)`), so it would result like:

```
awk '   
 NR >= 10000 { sum+=$2; array[NR]=$2 }
 END {
    total = length(array); 
    for(x=10000;x<=NR;x++) {sumsq+=((array[x]-(sum/total))^2);} 
    printf("%8.3f\t%8.3f\n"), (sum/total), sqrt(sumsq/total)  
 }'
```

Comment: You should mention that using `length(array)` makes it gawk specific.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes. It's important to note that, although he labeled it with `gawk`, for other users that could try to adapt a similar solution for their needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the math (wish you'd given a small testable example with, say 10 lines!) but it sounds like you want to do something like:

```
awk -v tailStart=1000 '
{ sumAll += $2; valsAll[NR] = $0 }
NR>=tailStart { sumTail += $2 }
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        do stuff with valsAll[i] and sumAll
    }
    for (i=tailStart; i<=NR; i++) {
        do stuff with valsAll[i] and sumTail
    }
}
' file
```

Comment: I get an error when I run this. The error I get is  [do stuff with valsAll[i] and sumAll]

Comment: You apparently tried to execute a script that says "do stuff with..." instead of first writing the code to actually do stuff with the arrays.